# How to use update_all on has_one relation in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails app I have a `User` class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :profile
  has_one :sorting

  has_many :people
  has_many :companies
  has_many :projects
  has_many :invoices
  has_many :payments

  ...

  def move_to(user)
    associations = %w(companies people projects invoices payments)
    associations.each do |a|      
      send(a).update_all(:user_id => user.id)
    end
    %w(profile sorting).each do |a|
      send(a).update_column(:user_id, user.id) # would like to use update_all here but not working
    end
  end

end
```

Is there a way to clean up my `move_to` method, so that I can run `update_all` on `has_one` relations as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the relations instead of associations:

```
def move_to(user)
  relations = [Profile, Sorting, Invoice, ...]
  relations.each do |relation|      
    relation.where(user_id: self.id).update_all(:user_id => user.id)
  end
end
```

But this would be dangerous if you have additional conditions on your associations.

Comment: Thanks. This looks good. Can you explain to a Rails n00b why this would be more dangerous than my initial version?

Comment: if you have something like `has_many :payments, -> { where("total > 100") }` on your payments association my method wouldn't take this into account... you would have to define it explicitly. And there would be code duplication... so I would only recommend my method if the logic of moving the associations to another user stays that simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a block when declaring an association.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile do
    def update_all(attributes={})
      update_column(attributes) unless attributes.empty?
    end
  end
end
```

You may be able to reduce this with a concern so that you only need to write it once.  However, this seems like a *very* long way to go simply to reduce two loops to one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use association_scope to get the `ActiveRecord::Relation` object on has_one relation:

```
%i[profile sorting].each do |a|
  association(a).association_scope.update_all(:user_id => user.id)
end
```